# apostrophe mark is sent with Backslash in javascript string which is being sent to php page using ajax as part of json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

apostrophe mark is sent with Backslash in JavaScript string which is being sent to php page using ajax as part of json object

```
var qry="SELECT 
invpurchaseitme.Code, 
invpurchaseitme.Description, 
invunits.Description,
    invpurchaseitme.StoreGroup 
FROM 
    invpurchaseitme 
LEFT JOIN 
invunits 
 ON 
    (invpurchaseitme.UOMCode = invunits.Code)
 WHERE (
   invpurchaseitme.Code LIKE '%d@t@%' 
    OR 
   invpurchaseitme.Description LIKE '%d@t@%' 
    OR 
   invunits.Description LIKE '%d@t@%' 
    OR 
    invpurchaseitme.StoreGroup LIKE '%d@t@%'
) 
    AND 
invpurchaseitme.StoreGroup='"+$("#StoreCode").val()+"' 
ORDER BY invpurchaseitme.Code ASC 
 LIMIT 70"
```

I am replacing `d@t@` character with a php variable in the php page using `explode()`  after it is being sent using ajax to the php page.  But what I get in the final query is `\'%variablename%\'` instead of  `'%variablename%'`. I have tried using  `slashes` for escaping `'` but the result is same. how to get string without `slashes`

Comment: if you are using jQuery's ajax, try setting `processData: false`

Comment: Please don't make queries in the client side, that's really serious threat. Users can change the query with for example firebug and do damage to your database system.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. `stripslashes(str)`.

```
http://us1.php.net/stripslashes
```